# XEP-0133: Admin Requests to Get a User's Roster - Returns Service unavailable

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd

I am trying to get a user's roster through an admin account on an ejabberd server.

This is what I am trying to do:

```
    <iq 
    id='get-user-roster-2'
    to='localhost'
    type='set'
    xml:lang='en'>
  <command xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/commands' 
           node='http://jabber.org/protocol/admin#get-user-roster'
           sessionid='2012-12-04T12:44:27.123921Z'>
    <x xmlns='jabber:x:data' type='submit'>
      <field type='hidden' var='FORM_TYPE'>
        <value>http://jabber.org/protocol/admin</value>
      </field>
      <field var='accountjids'>
        <value>myuser@localhost</value>
      </field>
    </x>
  </command>
</iq>
```

This returns:

```
    <iq from='server@localhost' to='server@localhost/server@localhost/' type='error' id='purple64033b0f'>
<ping xmlns='urn:xmpp:ping'/>
<error code='503' type='cancel'>
<service-unavailable xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas'/>
</error>
</iq>
```

Any ideas what this means and how I can fix it? I am new to XMPP.

Any pointers are appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

XEP-0133 Introduction:
There exists a set of common service-level tasks that administrators often need to perform in relation to Jabber/XMPP servers........**This document describes such a protocol by specifying a profile of Ad-Hoc Commands and associated Data Forms fields, rather than by defining a specialized and distinct protocol.**
XEP-0133  Requirements:
    **Enable users with appropriate privileges to perform common administrative tasks with respect to Jabber/XMPP servers and components.
    
Re-use existing XMPP and Jabber protocols wherever possible.**

> so i think that u dont have Ad-Hoc command or Data Form service.u can
>   check this with **sevice discovery XEP-0030**